# Add ; To Complete Statement. Please Help Developers

Tags: android

{changeInterruptionFiler(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE)}; {mRootLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)}; {mTVStats.setText("Now on do not disturb mode.")};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changeInterruptionFiler(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);

mRootLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

mTVStats.setText("Now on do not disturb mode.");